# Adding integer value to a list from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've an Xml file like

```
<SampleFile>
 <Data>
   <Element Val="8" /> 
   <Element Val="10" /> 
   <Element Val="12" /> 
   <Element Val="14" /> 
   <Element Val="16" /> 
   <Element Val="9" /> 
   <Element Val="11" /> 
   <Element Val="13" /> 
   <Element Val="15" /> 
   <Element Val="17" /> 
 </Data>
</SampleFile>
```

i need to read the attribute value of" Val" and convert it to Int32 , then sort and then add to the list

now i'm using like:

```
  List<Int32> lst = (XDocument.Load("\\Sample.xml").Descendants("Element").Select(l_Temp => l_Temp.Attribute("Val").Value.ToString()).Cast<Int32>().OrderBy(nTemp => nTemp)).ToList();
```

but its not working properly

please give me a better solution

Comment: In future, please give more details than "it's not working properly". Would you take your car to the garage and say "it's not working properly" and expect them to be able to fix it without knowing anything else? No, you'd say what was actually happening. Do the same for developer questions (whether here or elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's reformat the code a bit so we can actually see what's going on:

```
List<Int32> lst = XDocument.Load("\\Sample.xml")
                     .Descendants("Element")
                     .Select(l_Temp => l_Temp.Attribute("Val").Value.ToString())
                     .Cast<Int32>()
                     .OrderBy(nTemp => nTemp)
                     .ToList();
```

Now, your `Select` clause is selecting a sequence of strings - although the `ToString` call is unnecessary as `XAttribute.Value` is already a string.

You're then trying to use `Cast<Int32>` to convert those strings into integers. That's not what `Cast<T>()` does. It only performs reference an unboxing conversions. Fortunately, `XAttribute` has an explicit conversion to `int` which makes all of this much simpler:

```
List<Int32> lst = XDocument.Load("\\Sample.xml")
                           .Descendants("Element")
                           .Select(l_Temp => (Int32) l_Temp.Attribute("Val"))
                           .OrderBy(nTemp => nTemp)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Jon. What do you mean with "It only performs reference an unboxing conversions"

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459356.aspx

I think, this will help u..

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use a schema file here.